# Making mongodb queries in spring without pojo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am transitioning to spring data from `vanilla` java where it is possible to make `mongodb` queries directly without explicitly constructing `pojos`. I was wondering if Spring data has such possibilities. For example, the following code will return only documents that match the specified filter. Can this be done in spring data without `pojos`?

```
Document query = new Document();

 if(resourceType.equals("surname")){
    query.append("$and", Arrays.asList(
    new Document().append("timestamp",
    new Document().append("$gt", convertDateMinusFive(aTime))),
    new Document().append("timestamp", new Document().append
    ("$lt", convertDate(aTime))),
    new Document().append("requestParameters.name", reqParamValue)));
```